# Marshalling native .dll in C# with multiple pointers

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, mixed-mode

Having the following code in C++:

> - nConId is Connection Identifier
> - pParName the parameter name
> - pSubName the subParameter Name (if any)
> - pValue_out a pointer to a char array of lenght FCL_PAR_VALUE_LENGH
> - nValueSize the real size of pValue_out vector (at least FCL_PAR_VALUE_LENGH)

```
extern "C" MY_API int ReadParameter(const ConnectionId_T nConId, const char* pParName,
    const char *pSubName, char *pValue_out, const int nValueSize );
```

My try is:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int ReadParameter(ConnectionId_T pConId, IntPtr pParName,
    ref IntPtr pSubName, ref IntPtr[] pValue_out, int nValueSize);
```

I'm using the following code to call that function:

```
# nConId is returned from another function and the his value is 0

public const int FCL_PAR_VALUE_LENGH = 128; 

string param_string = "AUXF";
IntPtr pParName = (IntPtr)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(param_string);

string subparam_string = "T";
IntPtr pSubName = (IntPtr)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(subparam_string);

IntPtr[] aParValue = new IntPtr[FCL_PAR_VALUE_LENGH]; 

int returnedValue = ReadParameter(nConId, pParName, ref pSubName,
    ref aParValue, FCL_PAR_VALUE_LENGH);
```

When I run the code I get an **AccessViolationException**, so I guess there's something wrong in my call.

Do I've my marshall wrong? What do I've to change in the code in order to get the good reponse?

PS: I also know that the call returns also something to `aParValue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're working too hard with those `char*`s. It's perfectly legal (and encouraged) to marshal a `System.String` for input, and a `StringBuilder` for output.

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int ReadParameter(
    ConnectionId_T pConId, 
    string pParName, 
    string pSubName,
    StringBuilder pValue_out,
    int nValueSize);
```

usage

```
const int sbLength = 256; //use a domain relevant value
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sbLength + 1); //for null character, hard to say if you need it without seeing the C++ code, but easier to just add it than find out.
int result = ReadParameter(conId, "paramname", "paramsubname", sb, sbLength);
```

You haven't given any indication about the underlying type of `ConnectionId_T` so I'm assuming you've ruled that out as an issue.

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8w969hb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot :)